# Is this safe to install for the kernel?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, vmware

So I decided to try out VMware and lol about in Ubuntu (mess around with themes and test out commands) and I did install VMware successfully for the most part but I ran into this when launching it:

[image]

Here is information about my kernel and such:

http://pastebin.com/iKm6bCpq

Would this be safe to continue? I just don't want to mess my OS up
The VMware is: VMware Player 5.0.4 for Linux 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: vmware is a 3rd part app. I suggest you use KVM (virt-manager) + spice

Comment: As long as you trust VMWare's developers, yes. It's a kernel module, so it *adds* functionalities to the kernel, it doesn't really *change* it.

Comment: please start editing from my edit and not an newer one (I added in the image and someone keeps removing it ;) )

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for adding the image! I didn’t know you could do that

Comment: @kos so i can do it?

Comment: you need a certain amount of reputation to be able to do so ;-)

Comment: Several applications need a module to be loaded into the kernel. An external module loaded into the kernel *can* constitute a threat and *can* mess up the system, but anything running as root can (including a bad installation of a package). I'm trying to explain what you should consider in order to decide. Installing modules can be risky (meaning: it *could* cause the system to fail), however that's easily fixable by preventing the kernel to load the module (in the worst case using a Live ISO).If you trust whatever is trying to install the module just go ahead, personally in this case I would.

Answer (score 0):

> Would this be safe to continue?

In my experience I would say: yes, it is safe to continue.

The problem is missing kernel headers so not a big issue.

Comment: Did you mean missing kernel *modules*? I see no evidence of missing kernel *headers*